# Detecting rectangles in Image c#

Tags: c#, image-processing, aforge

I am trying to detect rectangular shapes in c# and with aforge.net.

The Problem is not the detection itself. It is to find a reliable algorithm to preprocess the image for detection. There is a lot of noise in the images:

[original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBaxG.jpg)

[image processing so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMm9n.jpg)

I use a SISThreshold and various dilatation and opening filters, as well as edge detection. 
The square between 3 and 4 is not detected. I think because of the uneven edge of the square.

Do you have a more reliable algorithm or some Tips to improve my detection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using using erosion to get rid of noise, or try **[BradleyLocalThresholding](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/0ad5b988-5613-d62a-22a9-cf41e39c139f.htm)** instead of SISThresholding.

Comment: Indeed the BradleyLocalThresholding leads to interesting results. I have achieved a good result with this Filtersteps: contrast up; gamma up; grayscale; Bradley, Fillholes, Opening(for removing noise), dilatation, fillholes.  This leads to perfect rectangles. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I believe that Bradley is good for images with gradients, which is what seemed to be the issue with the detection. Glad I could help!